# Postscript - document size

Tags: postscript

how to set page size in the postscript?
how to rotate the document to width?
.
.

```
%!
%% Example 1

newpath
100 200 moveto
200 250 lineto
100 300 lineto
2 setlinewidth
stroke

showpage
```

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I want(img): http://oi41.tinypic.com/15wjalh.jpg

Comment: See the example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072070/automatic-paper-selection-using-postscript?rq=1. To 'rotate' -- you cannot actually *rotate* the page inside the printer, can you? -- you need to rotate your drawing.

Comment: But, why - points? O_o :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the page size to A4 landscape use:

> << /PageSize [842 595] >> **setpagedevice**

before the first marking operator. Rotation is not needed.
Full PostScript reference is at http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf

Comment: Any reason why this wouldn't work for a file? I used it earlier and it worked like a charm. I checked out the postscript reference and it seems link they might have removed the postscript reference pdf?

Comment: The reason might be that the file contains code that inits the graphic system in its prolog section. The reference pdf can be found [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/actionscript/articles/PLRM.pdf)

Comment: I had too many `grestore`s so I guess it was popping it off the stack.

Comment: The reference pdf links above are defunct - here's the current link for those interested: https://www.adobe.com/jp/print/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To switch to landscape format:

Move origin from lower left to lower right corner,
then rotate the coordinate system 90 degrees.

```
595 0 translate % 595 is width of A4 paper in points
90 rotate
```